# Connect C# to Mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

I want to connect to mysql server from C#. I found some code on the net but somewhere there is something wrong because i get

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

error.

```
private void Initialise()
    {
        server = "dns to server";
        database = "db_name";
        uid = "root";
        password = "password";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
                            database + ";" + "UID=" +
                            uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
          OR
        connectionString = "Server=xxx.no-ip.org;Database=rdb;"+
                "Uid=root;Pwd=wHt2%Zt;";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            Console.Out.Write("SUCCESS");
        else
            Console.Out.Write("ERROR");
    }

private bool OpenConnection()  {
            try   {
                connection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex){                    
                switch (ex.Number) {
                    case 0:
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                        break;    
                    case 1045:
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I don't get any message on the console. I added `Mysql.Data` as a reference to my project and i used `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;`

I also tried connectig through gui but with no luck. Ideas ?

Edit 1 : with either connection string my program is still not working.

Edit 2 : OpenConnection method added.

Edit 3 : [This is the error i get !](http://pastebin.com/WE2BZrav)

Comment: Can you show the code for OpenConnection() ? Also try changing "PASSWORD=" to "Pwd="

Comment: question edited. my program does not get that far. i think that my problem is with connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString) this part.

Comment: if you wrap the line that throws the exception in a try catch block you will have more info about why is throwing the exception. Also try the changing what i said in the first post.

Comment: the problem was my setup. first problem : my password contained a semi colon. second problem : my server did not accepted remote login. i haven't test my code yet but i will test it tonight.  thanks a lot for your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

p.s.

http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

probably you need to change your approach...use a webconfig or app config to setup and read your connectionstrings from the config...

I would also recommend you to read this...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12300/An-ASP-NET-Application-Using-a-MySQL-Database

**UPDATE**

Based on your updated findings...there can be two problems, first double check your connectionstring, Second is to check if the user "root" has the required permissions.

Comment: i don't think my program is that much sensitive. i want it to work, them make it beauty.

Comment: app.config/web.config is beauty? i think it's a standard approach to store your connectionstrings. lazy usage.

Answer (score 1):

Look here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql
Have all.

Answer (score 0):

```
Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

I think the problem is your database server:

```
Server=xxx.no-ip.org
```

It seems your app doesn't find the server. Check firewall.

You can debug and set an interruption point and check which exception it's throwing, not just the number

Comment: My problem was the password. It contained ";" among other signs. I change it and now i get "ERROR". I have to investigate this error now.

Comment: Might not be the case here but dbs are often configured not to allow remote root login in MySQL I seem to recall. Might want to double check that root is allowed to connect remotely.

Comment: i will check that and come back with an answer.