# Save Query result in a variable

Tags: c#, mysql

Below is the query am using. Here am getting the sum of `weightagepercentage` column depending on the data in `status` column.

```
Status|WeightPer
___________________
P     | 2
F     | 3
F     | 1
P     | 1


SELECT Status, 
       SUM(WeightagePercent) AS Final
FROM ProoferTbl
GROUP BY Status
```

Final has

```
F=4
P=3
```

I need to save the result in  2 variables Pass and fail with the values and compare them for greatest. Is it possible to do so or do I have to change something?

Comment: Make connection with the DB from inside your C# programm and execute the query there. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185296/connect-c-sharp-to-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("...");
string strSQL = "SELECT SUM(case when Status = 'P' then WeightagePercent else 0 end) as passed, " + 
                "       SUM(case when Status = 'F' then WeightagePercent else 0 end) as failed " + 
                "FROM ProoferTbl2 " + 
                "GROUP BY Status";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, con);
con.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();   
int passed = 0, failed = 0; 
while (reader.Read())
{
    passed = (int) reader["passed"];
    failed = (int) reader["failed"];
}
reader.Close();
con.Close();
If(passed > failed)
{ 
    Messagebox.show("Pass")
}
```

Comment: This stores the values in pass and fail. Main thing i need is to compare these two and display the higest. Like 
If(passed>failed){
Messagebox.show("Pass")}. in C#

Comment: command.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(case when Status = 'P' then WeightagePercent else 0 end) as passed,SUM(case when Status = 'F' then WeightagePercent else 0 end) as failed FROM ProoferTbl GROUP BY Status"; int Result = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
getting cast error

Comment: Getting embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labelled statement at int. int passed = (int) reader["passed"];

Comment: @Robin: Yes, that was just to show you how it is done. I updated with real code

Comment: No Juergen i am getting a cast error. The final result i get from the query is a decimal.11.2

Comment: Well if your result is decimal then use a decimal as data type.